# awk: fatal: cannot open file `-v' for reading (No such file or directory)

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am new to awk. I know that -v means variable so I tried to do it in every variable from shell. But I do not know why I get this error. Can someone help me? Is there something wrong with my code?

```
        awk -v row_no=$row_no -v item=$item -v itemType=$itemType -v quantity=$quantity -v price=$price '{  NR==row_no;
                                                                                                                    $1=item
                                                                                                                    $2=itemType
                                                                                                                    $3=quantity
                                                                                                                    $4=price
                                                                                                                     }1' file.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt file.txt
```

The error that I got is:

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `-v' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this. Can you tell us which version of awk you are using and on which system you are running this?

Comment: You tagged your question with `bash`. The [`bash` tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) tells you "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting here" - please do that with future questions so we don't have to tell you about errors like this that the tool could've told you about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if your shell variables contain spaces, your awk command may fail, so, **please quote your variables**. e.g., `awk .... -v item="$item"....`

Second,

```
awk ... '{  NR==row_no;                                                         
$1=item
$2=itemTyp
....}1'
```

**The syntax is wrong.**

either `NR==row_no{...}` or `{if (NR==row_no){....}}`. What do you mean by the `1` at the end? Do you want to print all rows? if you just want to print the row with `NR==row_no`, you can put `print` into the `{...}` block and remove the `1`.

I *guess* your goal is to **update** the row with `NR==row_no` in the input.
If it is so, you can try this:

```
awk -v var="$shellVar" -v .... 
    'NR==row_no{$1=...; $2=...;$3=...;}1' input.file > tmp.file && mv ...
```

I think this little example simulates what you want:

```
$ seq 5 | awk -v row="3" 'NR==row{$1="hi"}1'
1
2
hi
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't quoting your shell variables, it is possible that one of them has a value with two words separated by a space. This makes the value undergo [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) and causes the first word to appear as part of the declaration and the other interpretted as a code.  This causes the following option which is a `-v` to be interpretted as a file argument and thus showing you the error ``` awk: fatal: cannot open file ``-v' for reading (No such file or directory) ```.  The first word may also just be an empty one.